# How do I generate random integers within a specific range in R?

Tags: r, simulation, exponential-distribution

I want to generate 100 random integers from an exponential distribution in R, where each integer is between 10 and 50 (hence 10, 11, 12, ..., 49, 50). How can I do this in R?

Comment: This appears more to be a question of "what to name a distribution with these parameters" than how to generate a subsection of an exponential distribution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You know the quantiles to which $10$ and $50$ correspond, right? These are given by `pexp(10, rate)` and `pexp(50, rate)`, respectively. With a `rate` of $1$, I get quantiles of $0.9999546$ and $\sim 1$, so you want exponential values between those quantiles.

Simulate from a uniform distribution with those values as the endpoints: `values <- runif(N, pexp(10, rate), pexp(50, rate))`. These will be the exponential quantiles of your simulated data.

Now pass those quantiles through the exponential quantile function: `x <- qexp(values, rate)` to look up their values.

This should generate exponential-y data that are limited to your range.

As has been noted, however, if you limit your range like this, you no longer have exponential data.

**EDIT**

Round as Henry describes if you are determined to have integers.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do I still have exponential data if I transform them linearly, for example with +20 of each integer?

Comment: @Tino If you limit your values beyond “all positive reals” then you do not have exponential data. // Depending on the rate parameter, a range from $10$ to $50$ is *really* far out in the tail. It makes me wonder if you have something else in mind.

Comment: I have generated some exponential data with set.seed and I checked that all values are between 0 and 12. My question is if I can transform them linearly (+20) to make them larger. Do I still have exponential data?

Comment: That’s iffy. You could call it a shifted exponential (I would), but the classical exponential distribution has a lower bound of $0$, not $20$.

Comment: This will not give integers: one approach would be to take your algorithm on the interval $[10,51)$ and then round down.  You actually get a truncated geometric distribution

Answer (score 5):

You can't "cap off" an exponential distribution. If you limit its values to a certain range it stops being an exponential distribution.

Here's a working example with the uniform distribution:

```
floor(runif(100, min = 10, max = 51))
```